# How to render UI controls in Xamarin Forms equivalent to Android native controls?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, binding

I am planning to integrate Phunware map within Xamarin Forms app. I am able to create Android Binding project so I can get packages equivalent to Phunware Android native SDK. By this I am able to access all methods and classes of Phunware SDK. Now the challenge is I have to follow Phunware Android native sample app source code, write equivalent code in Xamarin Forms and bring the map. I have given Android UI xml and activity file for sample.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.phunware.java.sample.LoadBuildingActivity">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.phunware.mapping.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/map"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/switch_floors" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/floorSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    package com.landt.ismartphunware2;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.phunware.core.PwCoreSession;
    //import com.phunware.java.sample.R;
    import com.phunware.mapping.MapFragment;
    import com.phunware.mapping.OnPhunwareMapReadyCallback;
    import com.phunware.mapping.PhunwareMap;
    import com.phunware.mapping.manager.Callback;
    import com.phunware.mapping.manager.PhunwareMapManager;
    import com.phunware.mapping.model.Building;
    import com.phunware.mapping.model.FloorOptions;

    public class LoadBuildingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPhunwareMapReadyCallback {
        private static final String TAG = LoadBuildingActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private PhunwareMapManager mapManager;
        private Building currentBuilding;
        private ArrayAdapter<FloorOptions> spinnerAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.load_building);

            Spinner floorSpinner = findViewById(R.id.floorSpinner);
            spinnerAdapter = new FloorAdapter(this);
            floorSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            floorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    FloorOptions floor = spinnerAdapter.getItem((int) id);
                    if (currentBuilding != null && floor != null) {
                        currentBuilding.selectFloor(floor.getLevel());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });

            // Create the map manager used to load the building
            mapManager = PhunwareMapManager.create(this);

            // Register the Phunware API keys
            PwCoreSession.getInstance().registerKeys(this);

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (mapFragment != null) {
                mapFragment.getPhunwareMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPhunwareMapReady(final PhunwareMap phunwareMap) {
            // Retrieve buildingId from integers.xml
            int buildingId = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.buildingId);

            mapManager.setPhunwareMap(phunwareMap);
            mapManager.addBuilding(buildingId,
                    new Callback<Building>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Building building) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Building loaded successfully");
                            currentBuilding = building;

                            // Populate floor spinner
                            spinnerAdapter.clear();
                            spinnerAdapter.addAll(building.getBuildingOptions().getFloors());

                            // Set building to initial floor value
                            FloorOptions initialFloor = building.initialFloor();
                            building.selectFloor(initialFloor.getLevel());

                            // Animate the camera to the building at an appropriate zoom level
                            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngBounds(initialFloor.getBounds(), 4);
                            phunwareMap.getGoogleMap().animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error when loading building -- " + throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Here, they are casting UI control to MapFragment and calling getPhunwareMapAsync() method. I just want to know in Xamarin Forms what control we can map to this MapFragment? In case we are about to write equivalent code in MainActivity of Xamarin Android project, how can we establish connection between PCL project and Android project and bring the map in View? I am just trying to figure out how to start and what to put where as I have excellent experience in Xamarin Forms but less experience with Android Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suggetion 1:

You could try using [Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps?view=xamarin-forms):

> Xamarin.Forms.Maps provides a cross-platform abstraction for displaying maps that use the native map APIs on each platform, to provide a fast and familiar map experience for users.

- [Xamarin.Forms Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map)

  - Basic usage about Xamarin.Forms.Map
  - Map functionality can be further enhanced by creating a [map custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/index).
- [Customizing a Xamarin.Forms Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/index)

  - This article explains how to create a custom renderer for the Map control, which displays a native map with a customized pin and a customized view of the pin data on each platform.

## Suggestion 2:

Customizing a `ContentPage` to display the Android native page that had a map along with some other controls:

> A ContentPage is a visual element that displays a single view and occupies most of the screen. This article demonstrates how to create a custom renderer for the ContentPage page, enabling developers to override the default native rendering with their own platform-specific customization.

- [Xamarin.Forms: Displaying a Native Android Page](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/xamarin-forms-rendering-a-native-android-page/)

  - In this case, it will display a content page that had a map along with some other controls. It demonstrate how to load a native android page within a Xamarin.Forms app.
- [Customizing a ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage)
- [Customize Your Xamarin.Forms App With Pages For Each Platform](https://blog.xamarin.com/customize-your-xamarin-forms-app-with-pages-for-each-platform/)

Comment: Thank you. I am about to follow suggestion 2

Comment: PhunwareMapManager.create(this); This method takes Context as argument. I am not sure how it should be done in Xamarin Android MainActivity. Can you help how to get the context in activity class and pass to this method?

Comment: @Ramesh, you could install [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin), then, you can call `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity` when you need to access the current activity: `Context CurrentContext => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity`.

Comment: Shen, excellent. It works. Also, I am able to bind classes, interfaces and methods in metadata.xml for Android. Can you please guide me how to do binding in metadata.xml for generic classes, for example Callback<Building> classes as in above code. If I am able to bind this generic class I will be able to complete the bindings and bring the map in Xamarin app. I am asking you because I am unable to find reference/help on and off internet on this.

Comment: @Ramesh, you could create a new question and post more detailed information about it, I will be there to help u.

Comment: Shen, as you suggested I have created a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332359/how-to-bind-generic-java-classes-in-android-binding-project-in-xamarin. Request to answer there. Thank you.

Comment: Shen , request to confirm if you would be able to provide a solution. Let me know if it is not possible also.